# I want to display Name1 to Name15 in ascending order but without just echoing each one

Tags: bash, shell

I have devised a way of outputting

```
Name1
Name2
etc.
```

To an extent. However with what I already have it only displays "Name" repeatedly without the integer on the end but I think I'm almost there. Can someone help me?

I read an article before about iterations so I am currently using one

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="Name"

END="15"
for ((I=1;I<=END;I++))
do
echo ${NAME}
done
```

I expect the output to be -

```
Name1
Name2
Name3 ... All the way to Name15
```

However the actual output is -

```
Name
Name 
Name
```

and so on...

Comment: Please use proper code formatting (every codeline inserted by 4 spaces), to make your post better readable.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq 1 15)
do
    echo "Name$i"
done
```